# R Program changes first value of matrix to 0 randomly

Tags: r, matrix, missing-data

I have a function that takes in a matrix with three columns. The third column is binary. If the value of the third column is 1, I would like to replace the value of the same row, but in the first column to 0.

When I created this function, it changes my value [1,1] of my matrix to 0 and I cannot figure out what the issue is. Help?

```
replace_if_miss = function(data){ 
    s = 1
    for (i in data[,c(3)]) {
        if (i == 1) {
            data = replace(data, c(s,1), 0)
        }
        s = s+ 1
    } 
    return(data)
}
```

For example I want this:

```
     x                      
 [1,] 0.4556397 0.4040319   0
 [2,] 0.8851506 0.398007    0
 [3,] 0.2407926 0.006787511 1
 [4,] 0.3375846 0.444135    0
 [5,] 0.1898765 0.2568749   1
```

To change to this:

```
  x                      
 [1,] 0.4556397 0.4040319   0
 [2,] 0.8851506 0.398007    0
 [3,] 0         0.006787511 1
 [4,] 0.3375846 0.444135    0
 [5,] 0         0.2568749   1
```

But it changes to this:

```
  x                      


 [1,] 0         0.4040319   0
 [2,] 0.8851506 0.398007    0
 [3,] 0         0.006787511 1
 [4,] 0.3375846 0.444135    0
 [5,] 0         0.2568749   1
```

Comment: I should add, it changes that value [1,1] when the corresponding third column is not 1. It changes it no matter what.

Comment: Does the line `for (i in data[,c(3)])` check for just the third column's value and set it to i?

Comment: No, for example I want this matrix: 

 [1,] 0.4556397 0.4040319               0
 [2,] 0.8851506 0.398007                 0
 [3,] 0.2407926 0.006787511           1
 [4,] 0.3375846 0.444135                 0
to change to 
[1,] 0.4556397 0.4040319               0
 [2,] 0.8851506 0.398007                 0
 [3,] 0                0.006787511           1
 [4,] 0.3375846 0.444135                 0

But with that code it changes to 

 [1,] 0         0.4040319         0
 [2,] 0.8851506 0.398007    0
 [3,] 0         0.006787511     1
 [4,] 0.3375846 0.444135    0

Comment: You may find Circle 3 of [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) particularly interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly set the value rather than relying on loops:

```
data[data[, 3] == 1, 1] <- 0
```

This is setting the value in column 1 to 0 when the value in column 3 is 1.

I think your function is replacing [1, 1] with 0 because when `s` is 1, `c(s, 1)` is `c(1, 1)`, which is set to 0.